# Laravel & Vuejs mixins : how to attribute a new value to shared variable?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, mixins

I can use the mixin variables `test` and the method `changeTest`, when when I attribute a new value to the variable `test`, it's only applied in one component. How to have it changed **globally**, on all components using it ?

My mixins are set in the file `resources/js/mixins.js`:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            test: 'foo',
        };
    },
    methods: {
        changeTest(v) {
            this.test = v;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I have my two components `comp1.vue` and `comp2.vue` in `resources/js/components/`, both  looking like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ test }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import myMixins from '../mixins'
export default {
  mixins: [ myMixins ],
}
</script>
```

Both components are in my `home.blade.php` like this:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<comp1></comp1>
<comp2></comp2>

@ensection
```

Comment: A mixin is a way for you to share the same logic between components but it will not share state (in the same way you can have multiple components that are the same). If you want data to be available globally I would suggest using something like Vuex https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for making a common variable (state) between all instances in vue.js you can use vuex. it's so simple, just add vuex to your packages and make an instance like this:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        test: 'foo',
    },
    mutations: {
        setTest(state, payload) {
            state.test = payload
        }
    },
});
```

now you need to add this store to your main vue instance:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.use(Vuex);

let vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    // ...
});
```

all done. now in every component you can access the states by `this.$store.state`. for making life easier, you can define a computed variable like this:

```
computed: {
    test() {
        return this.$store.state.test
    }
}
```

to change the state you just need to commit the setTest mutation. you have to add this mutation to methods and simply call it like this:

```
methods: {
    ...Vuex.mapMutations(['setTest']),
    myMethod() {
        // do this

        this.setTest('some value');

        // do that
    }
}
```

you can also make a global mixin like i told you before to add this computed and mutation to every instance like this: (add this before make the main vue instance)

```
Vue.mixin({
    computed: {
        test() {
            return this.$store.state.test
        }
    },
    methods: {
        ...Vuex.mapMutations(['setTest']),
    }
});
```

but i don't recommend to do this because when the project grow big, it gets so hard to avoid name confusion. it's better to make them separately for each component to chose proper names.

Answer (score 0):

you can use mixin method on main Vue instance like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import MyMixin from './mixins.js'

Vue.mixin(MyMixin);
```

It will apply this mixin for all instance no matter how deep they are.

Comment: It doesn't allow to attribute a new value to a mixin variable.

Comment: @maxagaz show me the piece of code and the error message, I'm pretty sure this works, I used it before

Comment: I mean, it doesn’t allow to attribute a new value *globally*, when I reset a mixin variable, the change is only available for the concerned component. So, there’s no error message.

Comment: @maxagaz this way each vue component have his own separate data. if you need a varible that is shared between all components then VueX is your answer. im going to make another answer to explain it.